# Right Channel to esclate Buddhism rules and regulation matters

Tags: compassion, wisdom, precept

Where is the right channel to escalate or feedback the Buddhism matters via email writing ? I am thinking write to [The World Fellowship of Buddhists (The WFB)](http://wfbhq.org/regional-centres.php?c=013000016) via email.

Comment: I'm sorry, this seems to be a question about covid masks, not about Buddhist teaching and practice.

Comment: @Andrei Volkov edited

Comment: well, this is still not about teaching or practice, but I did reopen it

Comment: @Andrei Volkov Thanks Andrei, me recently visited many charity clubs and monasteries to help out poor dad that badly infected with Covid. Many not wearing mask and have their own thoughts. I m confuse how they can help me while the simple thing that they dont follow about this Covid.

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know there's little or no world-wide "command structure" of Buddhists -- you can't write to one person and expect they'll pass a new edict that every Buddhist organisation will follow.

I'd guess that writing to "the WFB" is a bit like writing to the United Nations, i.e. unlikely to be effective.

It may be more effective to contact the specific organisations whose behaviour or whose publications you want to comment on -- i.e. the "charity clubs" and so on -- or to converse in person with people who are members of those organisations.

There may be some local organisations -- e.g. an abbot who heads a monastery; a senior reverend teacher within a school; perhaps even some national organisation (within a country).

Answer (score -2):

The Sangha isn't a social service and not part of common communities. And such institutions like mentioned, are 'illegal fakes'. One accumulates much demerits in thinking wishing to own and control the Buddhas heritage. RED (delusion) was many times in history already pain for many, foremost themselves. What if reminding that being still subject to aging, sickness, death, aparting from beloved and only owner and heirs of his actions, good, or bad?

Comment: i sent a polite email to them as feedback. 2ndly. where is the proof as  'illegal fakes'. ?It's quite big organization and i had visited them many times. Nothing i seen as  'illegal fakes'. neither from the internet feedback.

Comment: TQ for your kind feedback by the way

Comment: There is only one Buddhas organisation, and this is his Sangha of monks. Else is called thief, copy, fake.

Comment: They have sangha. Please continue at the chat room for further discussion